# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' , A problem came when I run my Django Project

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

When I try to run my Django project, it came an error:'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL''. I try install Pillow in my virtual environment, but it still can't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWaXp.jpg)

Comment: Make sure you have your virtual environment activated and please share the output of `pip freeze` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can install package by :

`pip install pillow`

Comment: thx, I solve the problem by using anaconda env : )